# Record raspivid and shut down safely

Tags: raspicam, script

I'm new to Raspberry Pi tinkering and I'm trying to make some slight changes to the [Adafruit 'Raspberry Pi Wearable Time Lapse Camera' project](https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-wearable-time-lapse-camera?view=all).

Instead of the camera taking pictures at a given interval until the slim button is pushed down, I'd like it to record a video for a given duration, then shut itself down. Here is the code I currently have:

```
# Configurable stuff...
INTERVAL=3        # Time between captures, in seconds
WIDTH=1920             # Image width in pixels
HEIGHT=1080             # Image height in pixels
QUALITY=51             # JPEG image quality (0-100)
DEST=/boot/timelapse   # Destination directory (MUST NOT CONTAIN NUMBERS)
PREFIX=img             # Image prefix (MUST NOT CONTAIN NUMBERS)
HALT=21                # Halt button GPIO pin (other end to GND)
FPS=30                 # FPS of video
DURATION=10            # Duration of video in seconds
LED=5                  # Status LED pin (v2 Pi cam lacks built-in LED)
starttime=0             # Time of last capture (0 = do 1st image immediately)

gpio -g mode $HALT up  # Initialize GPIO states
gpio -g mode $LED  out
mkdir -p $DEST         # Create destination directory (if not present)

# Record video
FRAME=$(($(find $DEST -name "*.h264" -printf %f\\n | sed 's/^[^1-9]*//g' | sort -rn | head -1 | sed 's/[^0-9]//g') + 1))
OUTFILE2=`printf "$DEST/$PREFIX%05d.h264" $FRAME`
raspivid -n -t $DURATION*1000 -w $WIDTH -h $HEIGHT -fps $FPS -o $OUTFILE2
starttime=$(date +%s)

while :         # Lasts as long as duration + 10 seconds
do
        currenttime=$(date +%s)
        if [ $(($currenttime-$starttime)) -ge $DURATION+10 ]; then
                gpio -g write $LED 1
                shutdown -h now
        fi
done
```

However the Raspberry Pi never shuts itself down, and when I have to manually turn it off I'm left with a 1 KB h264 file that causes VLC to spaz out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like timing the shut off is unnecessary, the `shutdown` command will wait until the `raspivid` command is finished.

So this code will work:

```
# Configurable stuff...
INTERVAL=3        # Time between captures, in seconds
WIDTH=1920             # Image width in pixels
HEIGHT=1080             # Image height in pixels
QUALITY=51             # JPEG image quality (0-100)
DEST=/boot/timelapse   # Destination directory (MUST NOT CONTAIN NUMBERS)
PREFIX=img             # Image prefix (MUST NOT CONTAIN NUMBERS)
HALT=21                # Halt button GPIO pin (other end to GND)
FPS=30                 # FPS of video
DURATION=30            # Duration of video in seconds
DURATIONMS=60000           # Duration of video in seconds
LED=5                  # Status LED pin (v2 Pi cam lacks built-in LED)
starttime=0             # Time of last capture (0 = do 1st image immediately)

gpio -g mode $HALT up  # Initialize GPIO states
gpio -g mode $LED  out
mkdir -p $DEST         # Create destination directory (if not present)

# Record video
FRAME=$(($(find $DEST -name "*.h264" -printf %f\\n | sed 's/^[^1-9]*//g' | sort -rn | head -1 | sed 's/[^0-9]//g') + 1))
OUTFILE2=`printf "$DEST/$PREFIX%05d.h264" $FRAME`
starttime=$(date +%s)
raspivid -n -t $DURATIONMS -w $WIDTH -h $HEIGHT -fps $FPS -o $OUTFILE2
gpio -g write $LED 1
shutdown -h now
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.